# Vertical scroll bar overlaps top static bar

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, stack-snippets, scrolling

In attached image, Vertical scrollbar just overlaps when code snippets is too big and am scrolling up on code snippet area that time vertical scroll will overlap to top static bar.

---

[image]